# Pass boolean value by reference

Tags: objective-c, boolean, pass-by-reference

Is is possible in objective c to pass a boolean value by reference? I have a number of boolean properties that I need to manage, so I'd like to encapsulate the toggling of these values into a single function that I can call from each button click event. Here is one example:

```
@interface MyViewController()
@property (nonatomic) BOOL *sendEmails;
@end
```

Then in a `UIButton` click event, I have this method call:

```
[self updateEmailPreference:self.sendEmails button:self.noEmailsCheckBox];
```

Which calls this method:

```
- (void) updateEmailPreference : (BOOL *) b
                        button : (UIButton *) button
{
    if (*b) {*b = NO;}
    else {*b = YES;}

    if (*b) {
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked_checkbox"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked_checkbox"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

But unfortunately, this crashes on the `if (*b)...` block. Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: your code does not make any sense. `if (b)` check the pointer not null, `if (*b)` check the value that pointer point to, you need to figure out which one to use

Comment: The above will only work if `sendEmail` *points* to a BOOL.

Comment: I'm not sure this is an accepted obj-c pattern. You're better off creating a class with the booleans in it, and passing that class back and forth as a return value from method calls. `NSError` is commonly passed around like you're proposing, but that is it.

Comment: @Aaron - But it's perfectly valid C to pass a pointer to a BOOL.  It doesn't have to be on someone's "pattern" list.

Comment: I'm not saying its invalid, I'm just saying its probably not the route you want to go with obj-c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably better to do:

```
@interface MyViewController()
@property (nonatomic) BOOL sendEmails;
@end
```

For the method call:

```
[self updateEmailPreference:&(self ->_sendEmails) button:self.noEmailsCheckBox];
```

With the method still:

```
- (void) updateEmailPreference : (BOOL *) b
                        button : (UIButton *) button
{
    if (*b) {*b = NO;}
    else {*b = YES;}

    if (*b) {
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked_checkbox"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked_checkbox"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

(Do note that there can be confusion about the variable to use in the call statement.  If it's a property you must use the ivar reference and not the dot-qualified property, and the ivar name must have the `_` prefix or not depending on how your properties are declared.  Or just use a local variable, and copy the property value into and out of that as required.)

Comment: not sure what will happen, but i think it is undefined behaviour. you actually need `&(self->sendEmails)`

Comment: Thanks. That's pretty much what I am looking for. However, I get an error `Address of property expression requested` on the method call.

Comment: @BryanChen - Yep, you're right -- sendEmails cannot be referenced through an accessor.  I edited to show the correction.

Comment: @usr55410 - No, just use the corrected version, with the `.` replaced by `->`.

Comment: @HotLicks I think you need to take the address of the backing ivar, in which case it would be `self->_sendEmails`.

Comment: Doesn't work. `'MyViewController' does not have a member named sendEmails'; did yo mean '_sendEmails'`. If I change it to '_sendEmails' it doesn't respond to the click. And I don't want to write getter/setter methods for every one of my properties as this defeats the purpose of encapsulating this in a single method. Any ideas? Am I missing something? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @godel9 - Yep, it depends on how you define your properties.  `_sendEmails` should work.

Comment: @usr55410 - What do you mean by "doesn't respond to the click"?

Comment: Looks like it works. Will you please edit your solution to show the iVar. I'll accept it with that change, just to be nice to others who might stumble on this some day. Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: Keep in mind that this `updateEmailPreference:button:` method assumes a non-nil value is always passed in for `b`. The app will crash if `nil` is ever passed in.

Comment: @rmaddy - Yep.  If one wishes to tolerate `nil` (as is typical with an `error` parameter) then additional `if` statements must be added to the method.

Comment: `self->_sendEmails` is the same as `_sendEmails`

Answer (score 1):

it crashed most likely due to dereference to null pointer, you have to make it point to some valid value

e.g.

```
@implementation MyViewController
{
    BOOL _sendEmailsVal;
}

- (BOOL *)sendEmails
{
    return &_sendEmailsVal;
}
```

---

also

```
if (*b) {*b = NO;}
else {*b = YES;}
```

can be replaced to

```
*b = !*b;
```

---

actually you don't need to pass pointer, it is mainly used to have more than one return value

```
@interface MyViewController()
@property (nonatomic) BOOL sendEmails;
@end

- (BOOL) updateEmailPreference : (BOOL) b
                        button : (UIButton *) button
{
    if (b) {
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked_checkbox"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked_checkbox"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    return !b;
}

self.sendEmails = [self updateEmailPreference:self.sendEmails button:self.noEmailsCheckBox];
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm sure that this will work for one boolean property, but I have quite a few of them. I'm trying to write a single method that will work for whatever boolean property that I pass to it.

Comment: @usr55410 the second version should works with whatever boolean property. you can replace `self.sendEmails` with any bool variable